# Is it possible to set flags when using make with Ansible?

Tags: makefile, ansible

I would like to know if it's possible to pass the following command in `ansible` using its `community.general.make` module:

```
make -C safenet install PREFIX=~/.local
```

Do I have to use `params`, as described [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/make_module.html)? E.g.

```
- name: installing safenet
  community.general.make:
    chdir: ~/myfiles/safenet
    target: install
    params:
      - "-C"
      - PREFIX=~/.local
```

This is the output I get.

```
TASK [Installing safenet] *******************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "argument 'params' is of type <class 'list'> and we were unable to convert to dict: <class 'list'> cannot be converted to a dict"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to pass the arguments using `params`. Since this module *does not* like using `~` as home folder, you will need to use variables or plugins to make it use the `home` folder of the current user (`$USER`). E.g.

```
- name: "Your task"
  community.general.make:
    chdir: /home/{{ lookup('env', 'USER') }}/path/to/makefile
    target: install
    params: PREFIX=/home/{{ lookup('env', 'USER') }}/path/you/want/to/use
```

The `{{ lookup('env', 'USER') }}` makes Ansible look up current username.